# How to get number of attendees or participants in an ongoing meeting using webex API

Tags: php, laravel, webex

I am using Webex API. I am stuck in one thing, Question is how can i get number of attendees or participant in an on going session ?

Answer (score 0):

, try to use GetMeeting on your XSD Documentation, if you use the XML API see this doc: https://developer.cisco.com/site/webex-developer/develop-test/xml-api/xml-api-reference/#getmeeting